# Sending Hex and String to UDP

Tags: cocoa, sockets, udp

I am trying to send commands to a server, through UDP. The server requires a few hex bytes at the beginning, though PHP this is easy

`'\xFF\xFFcmd command variable'`

Then I `fwrite()` that without a problem.

Now I am building a client in Cocoa and I cannot get the server to understand me at all, the data is sent, but I think it is incorrect or corrupt. I am trying to do it with CocoaAsyncSocket..

```
NSString *msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c%ccmd command variable",0xFF,0xFF];[socket connectToHost:@"85.25.248.160" onPort:28960 error:nil];

unsigned char lendata = [msg length];
NSMutableData *senddata = [NSMutableData dataWithBytes: &lendata length:sizeof(lendata)]  ;
[senddata appendData:[msg dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[socket sendData:senddata withTimeout:-1 tag:0];
```

NSLog of msg is 'ˇˇcmd command variable' but nothing occurs on the server, which I don't have access to, to listen for a malformed packet.

My guess is that by putting the 0xFF into the string, it is no longer the same, and is sent wrongly..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved problem. The NSString was messing with the \xff.

```
char *bytes = "\xff\xffcmd command variable";
NSData* data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:bytes length:strlen(bytes)];
[socket sendData:data withTimeout:-1 tag:0];
```

To get variable as an NSString or something else..

```
char *bytes = "\xff\xff";
NSString *commands = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"command %@", variable];  
NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithBytes:bytes length:strlen(bytes)];
[data appendData:[commands dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[socket sendData:data withTimeout:-1 tag:0];
```